# Overpass API: Find nearest intersection to lat/lng

Tags: openstreetmap, intersection, overpass-api

I have a lat/lng pair, and I need to find the nearest street and intersection.

For example: street X, corner with Y.

I have Nominatim and Overpass running.

My approach is:

- Get all ways near the lat/lng with Overpass
- Calculate distance between all nodes and my lat/lng
- Find the two closest to my lat/lng and that belong to different streets
- Those should be X, and then Y

Is there any better approach? I feel like I'm wasting CPU and underutilizing Overpass.

Also, I know that X and Y may not intersect at all. This only means they are close, nothing else.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: You should look at Postgis instead, Overpass won't give you the "nearest X"

Comment: Thanks MMD, will try that. I'm looking at https://github.com/kartoza/docker-osm to get a running PostGIS server. Do you happen to have a "get nearest intersection" example? If it is not too much to ask. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this :

```
node(around:80,-2.9027958824455133, -79.02495784310128)->.aroundnodes;
way(bn.aroundnodes)[highway~"^(residential|primary|secondary|tertiary)$"]->.allways;
node(w.allways)->.waynodes;
( 
  node.waynodes.aroundnodes; 
  way.allways.allways; 
 );
out;
```